# In VSS 6.0 How to enable working on single file with multiple people

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

How more then two people can work on vss with checking out file of diffrent in VSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VSS Administration goto Tools > Options > Enable multiple checkout.  Courtesy of [Vipul's blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/vipul/archive/2005/08/03/61328.aspx).

Also read Microsoft's guide on [team development with VSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998227.aspx).